# Autohotkey - Pausing Script and when unpaused show 'RUNNING' on tooltip

Tags: autohotkey

I would like my code to show 'paused' upon script being paused and **show 'running'** **for only a short interval** **after the script is unpaused**.

However, it did not work as expected.

My code below (commented the problematic issue):

```
NumpadEnter:: ; script is paused on said key and reactivated on said key
    Suspend
    ToolTip, PAUSED, 200, 250
    Pause ,, 1
; ; ToolTip, RUNNING, 200, 250 ; Code segment when un-commented does not work as it should
; ; Sleep 500                  ;
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 1
return

RemoveToolTip: 
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, Off
    ToolTip
return
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: what does it do currently?

Comment: what is does is that it: 


1) pauses the script upon hitting the NumpadEnter key and toottip "RUNNING" gets activated (tooltip "PAUSED" seems to either be bypassed or disappear too fast); 


2) upon hitting NumpadEnter again, script is unpaused and tooltip "RUNNING" is closed

---

Comment: I assume it has to do with `Pause`. The documentation says it stops the script current thread which might have the GUI tooltip https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NumpadEnter::
  Suspend
  Pause ,,1
  if A_IsPaused {
    ToolTip, PAUSED, 200, 250
  } else {
    ToolTip, RUNNING, 200, 250
    SetTimer RemoveToolTip, 1000
  }
return


RemoveToolTip:
  ToolTip
  SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, Off
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jim!